# Lock File Config masking not working

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-4.0

I'm using JMeter 4.0 with latest [Lock File Config plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/LockFile/?utm_source=jmeter&utm_medium=helplink&utm_campaign=LockFile) on windows 7,

It's working with file name, but the option `Also check filemask` is not working

> You can also specify a filename with wildcards to check for existing lock files

[image]

Error in log:

```
2018-03-27 14:13:01,124 DEBUG k.a.j.c.LockFile: Return filename: c:/temp/2.txt
2018-03-27 14:13:01,124 DEBUG k.a.j.c.LockFile: Return filemask: *2*
2018-03-27 14:13:01,124 INFO k.a.j.c.LockFile: and by wildcard at C:\temp*2*
2018-03-27 14:13:01,124 DEBUG k.a.j.c.LockFile: Return filemask: *2*
2018-03-27 14:13:01,124 DEBUG k.a.j.c.LockFile: Return filemask: *2*
2018-03-27 14:13:01,124 DEBUG k.a.j.c.LockFile: Return filemask: *2*
2018-03-27 14:13:01,125 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception: 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kg/apc/io/FileSystem
    at kg.apc.jmeter.config.LockFile.testStarted(LockFile.java:45) ~[jmeter-plugins-lockfile-0.1.jar:?]
    at kg.apc.jmeter.config.LockFile.testStarted(LockFile.java:21) ~[jmeter-plugins-lockfile-0.1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.notifyTestListenersOfStart(StandardJMeterEngine.java:215) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.run(StandardJMeterEngine.java:384) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kg.apc.io.FileSystem
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    ... 5 more
```

Is there a specific case mask can/should be used? or I shouldn't use this option? is there a dependency jar I should add?  is it OS specific issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kg/apc/io/FileSystem

You missing [jmeter-plugins-common](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/kg.apc/jmeter-plugins-common/1.4.0) jar in [JMeter Classpath](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath), download it from the above link, drop to "lib" folder of your JMeter installation and restart JMeter to pick the .jar up.

If the jar is not being automatically installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager) it makes sense to let JMeter Plugins developers and maintainers know about it, you can reach out to them via [JMeter Plugins forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/jmeter-plugins)